# Combine 2 arrays and allow same value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$title = array('new year', 'cuti bersama', 'cuti bersama');
$date = array('2018-1-1', '2018-1-10', '2018-2-13');
```

I combined them into

```
$title_date = array_combine($title, $date);
```

What i get is only 1 `cuti bersama`, it has same title but different date.
how to allow same title in combined array?

My expected output is like this:

```
array(
 [new year] => '2018-1-1'
 [cuti bersama] => '2018-1-10'
 [cuti bersama] => '2018-2-13'
);
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I've updated my question, thank you

Comment: Your expected output is not possible. Array keys should be unique

Comment: is there any alternatives?

Comment: As mentioned by @Eddie, You must have an unique key. Can you take the date as key whereas the title as value in array? Or even make it as an array of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the date is unique you can have it the other way around.

```
$title = array('new year', 'cuti bersama', 'cuti bersama');
$date = array('2018-1-1', '2018-1-10', '2018-2-13');

$title_date = array_combine($date,$title);

Var_dump($title_date);
```

https://3v4l.org/j44qh

And you can use array_filter to find all cuti bersama.

```
$searchFor = 'cuti bersama';
$filteredArray = array_filter($title_date, function($item) use($searchFor){
    return $item == $searchFor;
});

Var_dump($filteredArray);
```

https://3v4l.org/2tMiX